# How to save an image that has been visualized/generated by a Keras model?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, keras, object-detection

I am using [detecto](https://github.com/alankbi/detecto) model to visualize an image. So basically I am passing an image to this model and it will draw a boundary line accross the object and dislay the visualized image.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import save_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from detecto import core, utils, visualize

image = utils.read_image('retina_model/4.jpg')
model = core.Model()

labels, boxes, scores = model.predict_top(image)
img=visualize.show_labeled_image(image, boxes,)
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to convert this visualized image into Numpy array. I am using the below line for converting the image into numpy array :

```
img_array = img_to_array(img)
```

It is giving the errror :

```
Unsupported Image Shape
```

All I want is to display the visualized image which is the output of this model to my website. The plan is to convert the image into numpy array and then save the image by code using the below line :

```
save_img('image1.jpg', img_array)
```

So I was planning to download this visualized image (output of this model) so that I can display the downloaded image to my website. If there is some other way to do achieve this then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Detecto's documentation says the **utils.read_image()** is already returning a NumPy array.

But you are passing the return of **visualize.show_labeled_image()** to Keras' **img_to_array(img)**

Looking at the Detecto source code of **visualize.show_labeled_image()**, it has no return type, so it is returning None by default. So I think your problem is you are not passing a valid image to  img_to_array(img), but None.

I don't think the call to  **img_to_array(img)** is needed, because you already have the image as a NumPy array. But note that according to Detecto's documentation, **utils.read_image()** is "Equivalent to using OpenCV’s cv2.imread function and converting from BGR to RGB format" . Make sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can visit the official github repo of  [detecto/visualize.py](https://github.com/alankbi/detecto/blob/master/detecto/visualize.py)to find out the show_labeled_image() function it uses matplotlib to plot the image with bounding boxes you can modify that code in your file to save the plot using plt.save_fig()